# Merge CSVs using Python (or Bash)

Tags: bash, python-2.7, csv, merge

I have a set of CSV files in a folder and I'd like to merge them in one "super-csv". Some of the columns are available in all files, some not.

Fields in the output should just be empty, if it was not available in the source. If a columnname is the same over multiple CSV, it should fill the existing column (Name in the example)

File1.CSV

```
ID        Name       ContactNo
53        Vikas      9874563210
```

File2.CSV

```
ID     Name          Designation
23    MyShore    Software Engineer
```

Output Expected

```
ID        Name          ContactNo           Designation 
53        Vikas         9874563210
23        MyShore                          Software Engineer
```

I've already tried other solutions, but they cannot handle empty fields. eg. [merge csv files with different column order remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283363/merge-csv-files-with-different-column-order-remove-duplicates)

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: Are the input files sorted by ID? I guess a solution in bash would be cumbersome. In python the best way would probably involve a mapping from a ID to a tuple consisting of the values. After you processed all input files and built your mapping you can use it to create a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you can use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/index.html) module that allows to fill a dataframe from a csv, merge dataframe and then save the merged dataframe into new csv file.

For example :

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("file1.csv", sep=",")
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("file2.csv", sep=",")
final_df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how="outer").set_index('ID')

final_df.to_csv("result.csv", sep=",")
```

which would produce

```
ID,Name,ContactNo,Designation
53,Vikas,9874563210.0, 
23,MyShore,,Software Engineer
```

You would have to play with the `sep` argument to adapt to your files format.

Comment: Thanks! For two files this is working perfectly! Any solution on how to apply this to more files? (dynamic amount of files in the same folder)

Comment: For an unknow number of files, you can use the os module as describe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Comment: yes I know, sorry i may expressed unclear  - i meant on how to adapt the "final_df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how="outer").set_index('ID')" to more than 2 files? (or dynamically?) shall i create a for i to xx which just adds 1 and 2 , then 3 to the combination of 1 and 2 and so on?

Comment: Yes, you can loop on the csv files in your directory and declare before the loop : `final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID"]) `