# How to open and iterate through a list of CSV files - Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of pathnames to CSV files. I need to open each CSV file, take the data without the header and then merge it all together into a new CSV file.

I have this code which gets me the list of CSV file pathnames:

```
file_list = []
for folder_name, sub_folders, file_names in os.walk(wd):
    for file_name in file_names:
        file_extention = folder_name + '\\' + file_name
        if file_name.endswith('csv'):
            file_list.append(file_extention)
```

An example of my list is:

```
['C:\\Users\\Documents\\GPS_data\\West_coast\\Westland\\GPS_data1.csv',
 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\GPS_data\\West_coast\\Westland\\GPS_data2.csv',
 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\GPS_data\\West_coast\\Westland\\GPS_data3.csv']
```

I am struggling to figure out what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge CSVs using Python (or Bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528673/merge-csvs-using-python-or-bash)

Comment: This code is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Seams like you need to look up how to open and read a file in Python, this is well documented:     
https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html

Comment: You should not write that nested loop. https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to read in each line of a file, and write it to the new file. But remember to skip the first line that has the column headers in it.  I previously recommend the cvs module, however it doesn't seem like that is necessary, since this task does not require analyzing the data.

```
file_list = ['data1.csv','data2.csv']

with open('new.csv', 'w') as newfile:  # create a new file
    for filename in filelist:
        with open(filename) as csvfile:
            next(csvfile)   # skip the header row
            for row in csvfile:
                newfile.write(line) # write to the new csv file
```

Edit: clarified my answer.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about merging files. You're only building a list

Comment: What a legend! This is exactly what I've been trying to do, thanks for the help :)